# Wifi stops to work in idle

Tags: wifi

I checked Xfce power manager seems settings correct but laptop screen goes black after 10 minutes of inactivity.
Actually the problem is that shared Wi-Fi (configured using hostapd package) stops to work. After that I can't get WIFI to work again without system reboot.
**Here is what I have and what have tried:**

1. Linux debian-dell-netbook 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
2. RTL8188CE chip with latest driver installed from sources
3. Checked /var/log/* northing happens in logs
4. WiFi works in 802.11g, with 'n' I got the same issue.
5. sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce && sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce ips=0 fwlps=0
6. sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed

Comment: Solved
It's a bug in realtek driver. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=797709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in realtek driver.
Here is how to solve it:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=797709